# What is vacuum-assisted ultrasonication?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, gas-laws

This quote from a methods section of a paper:

> [samples were] ultrasonicated for approximately 30 min to ensure
> adequate dispersion of the components throughout the mixture. The
> solution was then degassed under vacuum-assisted ultrasonication for 1
> h to ensure removal of residual oxygen from the mixture...

I know what ultrasonication is. I know what degassing is - bubbling N2 through the solution.

When the author is suggesting vacuum-assisted ultrasonication am I right in my understanding that what they are suggesting is to use a pump to reduce the pressure of the solution during ultrasonication? I imagine this aids gas release by further reducing the partial pressure of the solution.

1. Is there special equipment for this? I'm not sure the membrane I use
   to seal the cuvette will be sufficient hold a strong vacuum.
2. Should I lower the pressure enough for the solution to boil?
3. What rate of nitrogen is reasonable? Is this like to defeat the purpose of the vacuum?
4. What difference will this make compared to ultrasonication and n2 flow through the solution at ambient pressure  - is the vacuum likely to be worth the effort?

Comment: The are caveats with vacuum sonication. The key question is what volumes are we talking about, what is your solvent and what is the apparatus? We routinely do this for HPLC but our eluent volumes are about 1 L.

Comment: What is the solvent? This is important, as different solvents behave differently - think about DCM vs toluene in a rotary evaporator. I don't know any practical example of vacuum degassing, but as no N2 is mentioned, I think they just applied a vaccuum to a container and put it in ultrasounds. If that is the case, then any RBF, or Schlenk tube, or similar would do it, I guess. But a setup like that works with a high-bp solvent; for things like DCM things get harder

Comment: The solvent is actually a viscous polymer - lauryl methacrylate (LMA) (80 wt%) and
ethylene glycol dimethacrylate (EGDM). Would expect around 50-100ml.

Comment: Vacuum degassing is also commonly used for viscous materials, such as when mixing PDMS with catalyst.  Without it, the crosslinked polymer product (e.g a cast film) is often full of bubble cavities.